# Matching A String And Return Preseted Number For The Given String

Tags: php

I Am In A Trouble.

Accutally In a form in php (Username,Password) i want to set the password for each username. Mean

```
if($fh == "Harry") {
$password = "123456";
}
```

It Can Be Easily Create. But Problem is that i have total 500+ username. So Its Not possible by me, to set each username's password by the given method.

On of my a Friend, Created This By this method. And I found his username's password setted by this type.

```
"Harry":"12345","Biswas":"789456","garry":"56894"
```

So I wanted to create, Like This.
So Please Tell Me. How Can I Create This ?

Comment: this type your speaking of is it a data in a file?

Comment: Does the 500 users know you will be storing their passwords in plain text?

Comment: yes devzero its in a txt file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a lookup array for your data:

```
$str = '"Harry":"12345","Biswas":"789456","garry":"56894"';

$passwords = array();
foreach( str_getcsv( $str) as $entry) {
    list( $name, $pw) = explode( ':', $entry);
    $passwords[$name] = $pw;
}
```

Then, just use their name as the key to find their password:

```
$fh = "Harry";
echo $passwords[$fh]; // 12345
```

Comment: @user2424807 - As it should. If you know the person's username and you want to set their password, all you have to do is: `$passwords["USERNAME"] = "NEW PASSWORD";`.

Comment: I Does Not Understanding what you saying. i just presetting the password. so if the user fill the form, then he no need to give the password. bots will take the password, which i setted, for his username

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data file looks like this `"Harry":"12345","Biswas":"789456","garry":"56894"`
and the data file name is `userpass.txt`

```
 $data = file_get_contents("userpass.txt");
 $records = explode(",", $data);

 foreach ($records as $record) {
    $record = preg_replace('/"/', "", $record);
    $userpass = explode(":", $record);

    //DO YOUR SQL STATMENT HERE

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, `password`) VALUES ('" . $userpass[0] . "','" . $userpass[1] . "')";
    //execute query
 }
```